# How to startActivity with ACTION_SEND Intent from inside an Android Service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have added flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK", yet I keep getting runtime error "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag."

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Shared via app |"+title);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Link);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share link!"));
```

I know I can use this code in an Activity, but is there a way to share directly through a service?

Comment: as I have mentioned and as you can see in the code, I have added the requisite flag, and yet it gives the same exception

Comment: ... to the wrong intent ...

Comment: I am new to Android, if you could elaborate, that would really be helpful, thanks

Comment: it is not about android ... it is about programming and more general thinking ...

Comment: I am guessing the Intent being passed to startActivity is not 'shareIntent' object directly, but 'Intent.createChooser...'
is that it?

Comment: bravo! did you try to store it in some variable and add this flag? https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#LC878 https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ChooserActivity.java

Comment: I will do that now, and return if it DOES NOT work, thanks!

Comment: [There is yours answer... Right here at StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348125/is-it-possible-to-launch-an-activity-or-raise-an-intent-from-static-method-in-ap?rq=1

Comment: thanks Selvin and Pes :)
I mistakenly assumed that the problem was due to trying to start an activity from a service and stopped there. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the flag to the createChooser Intent:

```
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share");
chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```